# array, copy pixels to correct index, algorithm

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, c

I have image size is 2x2, so count pixels = 4

one pixel - 4 bytes

so I have an array of 16 bytes - mas[16] - width * height * 4 = 16

I want to make the same image, but the size is more a factor of 2, this means that instead of one will be four pixels

new array will have size of 64 bytes - newMas[16] - width*2 * height*2 * 4

problem, that i can't correct copy pixels to newMas,that with different size image correctly copy pixels
[image]

this code copy pixels to mas[16]

```
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
    const size_t bytesPerRow = width * 4;
    const size_t bitmapByteCount = bytesPerRow * height;
    size_t mas[bitmapByteCount];
    UInt8* data = (UInt8*)CGBitmapContextGetData(bmContext);

      for (size_t i = 0; i < bitmapByteCount; i +=4)
        {
            UInt8 a = data[i];
            UInt8 r = data[i + 1];
            UInt8 g = data[i + 2];
            UInt8 b = data[i + 3];

            mas[i]   = a;
            mas[i+1] = r;
            mas[i+2] = g;
            mas[i+3] = b;        

        }
```

Comment: Or you could just draw the image to a bigger context with antialiasing turned off...

Comment: pixels do not lose their color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, using the built-in image drawing API will be faster and less error-prone than writing your own image-manipulation code. There are at least three potential errors in the code above:

- It assumes that there's no padding at the end of rows (iOS seems to pad up to a multiple of 16 bytes); you need to use CGImageGetBytesPerRow().
- It assumes a fixed pixel format.
- It gets the width/height from a CGImage but the data from a CGBitmapContext.

Assuming you have a UIImage,

```
CGRect r = {{0,0},img.size};
r.size.width *= 2;
r.size.height *= 2;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(r.size);
// This turns off interpolation in order to do pixel-doubling.
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGInterpolationNone);
[img drawRect:r];
UIImage * bigImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```